# Get order title value from $order variable

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have to get order status and order title from $order variable. I can get order status by `$order->order_status`. But I can't able to get order title. So how to get order title value from $order variable programmatically.

I am using the below hook :

```
  function hook_uc_order($op, $order, $arg2) {
     if ($op == 'update') {
       if (($order->order_status == 'payment_received') && ($order->title == 'My Product')) {
         // Do something with the $order object.
       }
    }
  }
```

Here `$order->order_status` is working individually but `$order->title` is not working. How to get Order Title?

Looking forward for this answer.

Comment: Orders don't have a title...

Comment: Thanks. So how to get order name or specific product name here?

Comment: You might need to consider using the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and check the variable order by placing this code  `dsm ( $order )` inside your `hook_uc_order`.  it will display all the variables you need when you load the relevant php page for your custom code. it's really helpful when you are developing a custom module.

this is the method in ubecart API to get the product list. [ubecart drupal 7 - uc_order_get_product_list  ](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart%21uc_order%21uc_order.module/function/uc_order_get_product_list/7)

Comment: `dsm($order) ` is drupal way of dumping the content. it's like `var_dump($order)` in PHP. more developer friendly interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the order title from this method.

```
   uc_order_page_title($order)
```

check out all the methods you need for ubecart. [ubecart drupal 7 API](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart%21uc_order%21uc_order.module/7)